# How to define non-exploitability in the difficulty update algorithm?

Tags: timestamp, difficulty

In [enter link description here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Design-Rationale#difficulty-update-algorithm), it is said that "We have already determined that our current algorithm is highly suboptimal on low volatility and non-exploitability, and at the very least we plan to switch the timestamps compares to be the parent and grandparent, so that miners only have the incentive to modify timestamps if they are mining two blocks in a row."

What does the 'switch' mean here? Besides, I think the homestead version is good enough. Where is the disadvantage?

Comment: "non-exploitability" is defined in the section you linked to. "Switch" means "change".

Comment: Thanks, but how will miners benefit from changing timestamps when mining two blocks in a row? What does "we plan to change the timestamps compares to be the parent and grandparent" mean??

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your original question very well. Does it get answered in the other question you posted? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/74059/are-the-timestamps-of-blocks-for-ethereum-only-accepted-when-they-are-monotonica

Comment: emmm, I just want a more clear explanation on "at the very least we plan to switch the timestamps compares to be the parent and grandparent, so that miners only have the incentive to modify timestamps if they are mining two blocks in a row." Where and what is the incentive?